# Admin on rest show state data in List

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I am using admin on rest in my current project and facing problem in order to show result in the listView.

So currently i am uploading a csv file using create form and storing the response of the api in the state using action and reducer which is creating the response as a global state. The data from the state is fed to the props from where it can be displayed in the Datagrid. The data comes to the list but then it disappears in a moment as list searches for GET_LIST method in the rest client.

Please do advice how to overcome this problem!
Thanks in advance! :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import { fetchUtils } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { csvFailedRecords  as csvFailedRecordsAction } from '../customActions/csvFailedRecords'
import { showNotification as showNotificationAction } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { push as pushAction } from 'react-router-redux';
import {CREATE} from 'admin-on-rest'
import restClient from '../../App'

class UploadButton extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const { csvFailedRecords, record, push, basePath} = this.props
        let csvform = new FormData()
        if (record && record.length) {
            csvform.append('csvFile', record[0].rawFile);
        }
        // csvFailedRecords(record[0].rawFile)
        // restClient(CREATE, 'uploadCsv', { data: csvform})
        return fetchUtils.fetchJson(`http://localhost:3001/uploadCsv`, { method: "POST", body: csvform })
            .then(failedRecords => {
                console.log('failedRecords: ', failedRecords.json);
                csvFailedRecords(failedRecords.json)
                // showNotification(' Failed Records fetched');
                push('/upload')
            })
    }
    render() {
        console.log();
        return (<FlatButton label='Approve' onClick={this.handleClick} />)
    }
}

UploadButton.propTypes = {
    csvFailedRecords: PropTypes.func,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    showNotification: PropTypes.func,
    push: PropTypes.func, 
    basePath: PropTypes.string
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    console.log('state67890: ', state);
    return {
        record: state.form["record-form"].values.csvStorage
    };
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    csvFailedRecords: csvFailedRecordsAction,
    showNotification: showNotificationAction,
    push: pushAction,
})(UploadButton)





import React,{Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Datagrid, TextField, List,Show} from 'admin-on-rest'

class UploadDatagrid extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log('nextState: ', nextState);
        console.log(' this  state: ', this.props);
        console.log('nextProps: ', nextProps);
        return (nextProps, this.props);
    }
    render(){
        const { record, basePath, ids, data } = this.props
        console.log('data890000000: ', record);
        return(
            <Datagrid data={data} currentSort={{ field: 'tale_id', order: 'DESC' }} ids={ids}>
                <TextField source="tale_id" label="Id" />
            </Datagrid>
        )
    }
}


UploadDatagrid.propTypes = {
    record: PropTypes.object, 
    basePath: PropTypes.string,
    ids: PropTypes.array,
    obj: PropTypes.object
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    console.log('record78900000000: ',state.data.data.data);
    let sampleRecord = state.data.data.data
    const ids = sampleRecord.map(resp => parseInt(resp.tale_id))

    let data = {}
    sampleRecord.forEach(res => {
    data[parseInt(res.tale_id)] = res
    })
    return {
        record:state.data.data.data,
        ids,
        data
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UploadDatagrid)
```